# Why won't image 1 move to the right?

Tags: processing

I'm very new to coding and was wondering how I could make this image move to the right. I added all of my code so that it would be a bit more understandable for what's going on. The moveRight command will not actually move the png to the right which is why I need help fixing and understanding why it won't work. If someone can please help me it would be greatly appreciated.

```
 PImage background, backgroundGameState1, headbasketballbackground, player1, player2;
boolean moveRight, moveLeft;
int canvasSizeX= 1000;
int canvasSizeY = 600;
int mainBackgroundX = 1000;
int mainBackgroundY = 600;
int gameState1 = 1;
int player1X = 100;
int player1Y = 200;
int player2X = 100;
int player2Y = 200;
int backgroundGameState1X= 1000;
int backgroundGameState1Y=600;
int time;
int player1MovmentX = 100;
int player2MovmentX = 700;


void setup() {
  //size of canvas
  size(1000, 600);
  //Loaded images and called them, also made sure to resize them in order to match the canvas size or to make program more asthetically pleasing
  background = loadImage("headbasketballbackground.png");
  background.resize(mainBackgroundX, mainBackgroundY);
  backgroundGameState1 = loadImage("backgroundgamestate1.png");
  backgroundGameState1.resize(backgroundGameState1X, backgroundGameState1Y);
  player1 = loadImage("steph.png");
  player1.resize(player1X, player1Y);
  player2 = loadImage("paul.png");
  player2.resize(player2X, player2Y);

  time=millis();
}

void draw() {
  if (gameState1 == 1) {
    background(backgroundGameState1);
    if (millis() > time + 1000) {
      text("Click On Space To Enter The Game!", 100, 100);
      textSize(50);
      // delay(3000);
    }
    drawGameState1();
  }     
  if (gameState1 == 2) {
    background(background);
    image(player1, player1MovmentX, 300);
    image(player2, player2MovmentX, 300);
  } 
  //  if (gameState2 == 3) {
  //  text("Congrats you won!");
  //}
}

void drawGameState1() {
}
void drawGameState2() {
  drawPlayer1Movment();

}
void drawPlayer1Movment(){
    if(moveRight){
  player1MovmentX += 25;
}
}
void drawGameState3() {
}


void keyPressed() {

  if (gameState1 == 1) {
    if (keyCode == 32) {
      gameState1 = 2;
    }
  }
  else if(gameState1 == 2){
    if(keyCode == RIGHT){
    moveRight = true;
  }
    
  }
 
 
}
void keyReleased(){
  if(keyCode == RIGHT){
  moveRight = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I suggest tagging the programming language you are using.

Comment: Please add the language of your code after the `\`\`\`` for instance :  `\`\`\`c` or `\`\`\`cpp` . also you should add the language to the tags of your publication, for the moment only [processing] tag is listed.

Comment: Source code listed above will run in Processing IDE, Java mode: https://processing.org

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you ever called drawPlayer1Movement().  Add it to keyPressed() and player1 should move to the right when you hit the right arrow.

```
void keyPressed() {
  if (gameState1 == 1) {
    if (keyCode == 32) {
      gameState1 = 2;
    }
  } else if (gameState1 == 2) {
    if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
      moveRight = true;
      drawPlayer1Movment();
    }
  }
}
```